# one activity to another one

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to make the main activity which have some buttons ,how can i jump from activity to  another one . Why when i pressed the button he said : Unfortunately , mynameapp has stopped

This work properly :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    BlackPixel blackPixel;
    blackPixel = new BlackPixel(this);
    setContentView(blackPixel);
    blackPixel.requestFocus();

    });

}
```

Why this don't work ?:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

//        BlackPixel blackPixel;
//        blackPixel = new BlackPixel(this);
//        setContentView(blackPixel);
//        blackPixel.requestFocus();


        Button buttonSave=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonDraw);
        buttonSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,ButtonDraw.class));
            }
        });

    }
```

Here is the buttonDraw class :

```
public class ButtonDraw extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


          BlackPixel blackPixel;
          blackPixel = new BlackPixel(this);
          setContentView(blackPixel);
          blackPixel.requestFocus();
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myfirstapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
         >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.buttons.ButtonDraw"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.buttonDraw" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- yes you can go to another `Activity` by

```
 startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,ButtonDraw.class));
```

2- Yes you can close your `Activity` with following code after above code:

```
  this.finish();
```

for the learning about activity use this [link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/) and [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can write the following line in  of `Androidmanifest.xml`:-

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

then you don't need to write `finish()` every time

Comment: yes i mention the activity in the manifest xml , i just update the code on top

Comment: Where should i put this ?: android:launchMode="singleInstance"

Comment: in menifest's <activity> tag